# Handle an object's object property changed event in .NET Windows Forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, properties, event-handling

I know how to handle a single objects property changed event very easily. I want to handle a objects property changed event that is part of another object.

Given `Object`:

```
[ObjectY = Y]
+ Public WithEvents X As ObjectX
```

I would like to do something like:

```
Private Sub XPropertyChanged() Handles Y.X.PropertyChanged
```

Right now I need to create a object that equals the object inside that object and then handle this variable pointers property changed, but that is just annoying. Is there any way to do something similar to the above?

Comment: Do you have any hierarchical links between Objects? Or what you want to do is handle 2 totally different events with no link whatsoever?

Comment: So `ObjectY` and `ObjectX` derive from the same base classes? ...where is `Private Sub XPropertyChanged()...`? If ObjectY owns ObjectX, I recommend making the property public. Are these actual forms you are trying to work with ...e.g., FormA is supposed to handle an event from FormB's TextBox ...???

Comment: Have each object implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ...then it will become quite obvious how to bubble up the event from composite objects.

Comment: You may consider having a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4218764/763026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was a comment:

> Have each object implement INotifyPropertyChanged ...then it will
>   become quite obvious how to bubble up the event from composite
>   objects.