# Alternatives to OnPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to work out an issue I'm having with implementing MVVM in WPF. My `Contact` class below is my model that's being populated by Entity Framework.

```
public class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged implementation omitted for brevity
}
```

Here's my ViewModel:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public Contact MyContact { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return MyContact.FirstName + " " + MyContact.LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

So I set my View's datasource to an instance of `ContactViewModel`, and I'm binding two TextBoxes to `MyContact.FirstName` and `MyContact.LastName`. I'm binding a `TextBlock` to `FullName`. When I change either of my TextBoxes the Full Name `TextBlock` doesn't update (obviously, I'm not doing an `OnPropertyChanged("FullName")` anywhere).

The question is, where do I add `OnPropertyChanged("FullName")`? **I don't necessarily want to modify my model because it's being used elsewhere and I don't to tie it to my ViewModel.**

Do I need to rethink my architecture?

Comment: Normally it's the ViewModel that implements the INPC interface, not the model.

Comment: If that were the case, how would I bind to my model?

Comment: Some people duplicate the properties on their viewModel. These properties wrap the properties on the model and your view only binds to your viewModel. Both approaches are valid.

Comment: Precisely, the viewmodel contains only properties that need to be displayed or manipulated by the view.  The properties in the VM use the property of the model as their backing field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Do I need to rethink my architecture?*

This can be solved with your current architecture. You just need to propagate the call from your `Contact` object to your viewModel object.

You will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the viewModel to achieve this.

Something *like* this:

```
public class ContactViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //INotifyPropertyChanged implementation omitted for brevity...

    private Contact _myContact;

    public Contact MyContact 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _myContact;
        } 
        set
        {
            _myContact.PropertyChanged -= myHandler;
            _myContact = value;
            _myContact.PropertyChanged += myHandler;
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return MyContact.FirstName + " " + MyContact.LastName;
        }
    }

    private void myHandler(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
    }
}
```

I would also recommend taking a look at [MVVM Foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/) as this includes a class called `PropertyObserver` which is designed to make wiring up this sort of thing much easier.

If you want to take the more MVVM pure approach suggested by Big Daddy, you would need to do something *like* this:

```
public class ContactViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation omitted for brevity...

    // You will require some way of setting this, either via a property
    // or the viewModel constructor...
    private Contact _myContact;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _myContact.FirstName; }
        set
        {
            _myContact.FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _myContact.LastName; }
        set
        {
            _myContact.LastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return MyContact.FirstName + " " + MyContact.LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the question: I don't necessarily want to modify my model because it's being used elsewhere and I don't to tie it to my ViewModel.

Comment: So this would trigger OnPropertyChanged("FullName") when any property changes, and not just FirstName or LastName, correct?

Comment: @MikeCole Yes, but that's easy to avoid if you want by just adding an `if (e.PropertyName == "FirstName" || e.PropertyName == "LastName")` check to your property change handler. (Also, you'll want to check if `_myContact` is `null` before trying to attach and detach the `PropertyChanged` handler in your setter)

Comment: @Mike Cole - What Rachel said ^

Comment: Let me play around with this a bit to make it apply to my case. I think it's what I need though.

Comment: @Rachel I think this is the 2nd time you've helped me today, thanks!

Comment: How would this apply to child objects of Contact? It appears I might have simplified my example a bit much.

Comment: Do the child objects also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps it's just the syntax of hooking to a child object.

Comment: `ParentObject.ChildObject.PropertyChanged += ...` although if you are propagating more than a couple of levels deep you may want to re-think your approach. My answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15907840/577417) question may help.

Comment: Intellisense isn't picking up the events on child class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29756/discussion-between-benjamin-and-mike-cole)

Answer (score 1):

```
Do I need to rethink my architecture?
```

Maybe...

It looks to me like you're binding your view's properties to your view-model (ContactViewModel) *and* your model (Contact). Your view can see your public model's properties, etc. via your view-model - I don't think this is good.  It looks like a violation of the `Law of Demeter`.  I'd rather see you use your view-model as a wrapper/façade to your model.  This creates more work for sure, but I think it gives you a better design and more flexibility.  Your view-model will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this to work.

Comment: The issue with this is that my model implements IDataErrorInfo and has validation. Right now this is being passed through to my View and is handled gracefully. Would I lose those validation rules if I mapped to properties of my ViewModel?

Comment: Personally I see nothing wrong with binding directly to the Model, especially in smaller applications with only a single developer working on both the Model and ViewModel layers. It's not the "MVVM-purist" approach, however it's more practical since it's less work and code-duplication.

Comment: @Rachel...You've got a point if it's for a small app, but my experience says otherwise if it's not

Comment: @MikeCole...You still keep your validation rules in the model, if you want.  You'll just call YourPrivateModel.RaisePropertyChanged() in the VM's property.  I can post more code if you'd like.

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't the view need to be bound to an entity that implemented IDataErrorInfo to get the automatic validation? How could I reuse the rules that were in the model if I change the binding to use the ViewModel?

Comment: @MikeCole...No it doesn't, the VM serves as a wrapper to the model.  Here's a most excellent article written by Josh Smith that illustrates the point better than I can - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx.